# How to Create balloon like menu (no qtip plugin please)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I create a balloon like menu like twitter after click on ti?

[image]

I found qtip plugin which is fine but now what I am looking for

any tips are appreciated

Comment: Since you have a working example, why don't you just look at how they built theirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to display a `backgroud-image`, like:

```
#someId{
  display:none; background:url('imageWithTransparency.png'); /*more CSS here*/
}
#someId:hover{
  display:block; /*more CSS here*/
}
```

or

```
#someId{
  display:none; background-image:url('imageWithTransparency.png'); /*more CSS here*/
}
#someId:hover{
  display:block; /*more CSS here*/
}
```

I prefer the shortcut.